ORA-01861: literal does not match format string , how to fix this error?
this is my table
CREATE TABLE acctmanager
(
  amid CHAR(4),
  amfirst VARCHAR2(12) NOT NULL,
  amlast VARCHAR2(12) NOT NULL,
  amedate DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
  amsal NUMBER(8,2),
  amcomm NUMBER(7,2) DEFAULT 0,
  region CHAR(2),
  CONSTRAINT acctmanager2_amid_pk PRIMARY KEY (amid)
  CONSTRAINT acctmanager2_region_ck
  CHECK (region IN ('N', 'NW', 'NE, 'S', 'SE', 'SW', 'W', 'E'))
); 

I'm trying to insert first account manager data into table acctmanager using the following command
INSERT INTO acctmanager
VALUES ('T500', 'NICK', 'TAYLOR', '05-SEP-09', 42000, 3500, 'NE');


not a big Oracle master, but have you tried TO_DATE('05-SEP-09','DD-MON-YY') ?

'05-SEP-09' is not a DATE; it is a string literal that happens to look like a date.
Oracle will try and be helpful and try to implicitly convert your string to a date and your query will effectively become:
INSERT INTO acctmanager
VALUES (
  'T500',
  'NICK',
  'TAYLOR',
  TO_DATE(
    '05-SEP-09',
    (SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')
  ),
  42000,
  3500,
  'NE'
);

However, if the NLS_DATE_FORMAT session parameter does not match your string literal then it will fail with the error:
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Or a similar error (or worse, your query will succeed but Oracle expected the format YYYY-MM-DD and converts 05-SEP-09 to 9th September 5AD and you have invalid data that is out by about 2000 years).
To fix it you can:

Use a date literal:
INSERT INTO acctmanager (
  amid, amfirst, amlast, amedate, amsal, amcomm, region
) VALUES ('T500', 'NICK', 'TAYLOR', DATE '2009-09-05', 42000, 3500, 'NE');


Use a timestamp literal:
INSERT INTO acctmanager (
  amid, amfirst, amlast, amedate, amsal, amcomm, region
) VALUES ('T500', 'NICK', 'TAYLOR', TIMESTAMP '2009-09-05 00:00:00', 42000, 3500, 'NE');


Explicitly convert the date and specify the format (and language):
INSERT INTO acctmanager (
  amid, amfirst, amlast, amedate, amsal, amcomm, region
) VALUES (
  'T500',
  'NICK',
  'TAYLOR',
  TO_DATE('05-SEP-09', 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English'),
  42000,
  3500,
  'NE'
);


Change the NLS_DATE_FORMAT:
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-RR';

However, this is considered bad practice as you are still relying on an implicit cast and it is better to be explicit about what format you are using.


fiddle
